# Defcous Node algorithm

Tags: rendering, node-editor

I am working with Blender to generate defocus images using the Defocus filter it provides in the Node Editor. The official doc says that the blurring is done as a "post-process" using the Z values in the Z-Buffer. 
Can someone explain to me what is the actual algorithm in place for doing that? How does blender's defocus give pretty realistic images with just a post-process?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A quick look over the code [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/compositor/nodes/COM_DefocusNode.cpp), looks like it does a fast gaussian blur, a bokeh image and a variable size bokeh blur.